# Ponteiro é perdido na saída da função

Tags: c

Tenho a seguinte função

```
typedef struct userDataStruct
{
    char name [MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1];
    struct userDataStruct *next;
} userDataType;

errorType GetUsers (userDataType **list)
{
    FILE *file;
    char buffer [LINE_LENGTH+1];
    userDataType *first, *previous, *new;

    file = fopen ("abc.dat", "r");
    first = previous = NULL;

    while (fgets (buffer, LINE_LENGTH+1, file))
    {
         new = (userDataType *) malloc (sizeof (userDataType));

         /* Resto do codigo */

        if (first == NULL)
            first = new;

        if (previous != NULL)
            previous->next = new;

        previous = new;
    }

    list = &first;

    return ok;
}
```

(ignorem qualquer erro de sintaxe, tive que dar uma enxugada)

Quando eu preciso chamar essa função, declaro um ponteiro e passo ele com o valor nulo. Por exemplo:

```
int main (void)
{
    userDataType **usersList = NULL,
            *currentUser;
    GetUsers(usersList);

    currentUser = *usersList; /* Aqui está o erro */
}
```

Na linha indicada, a variável *currentUser* está com o valor nulo.

Se eu usei a função *malloc* para alocar a memória, essa variável não deveria estar apontando para o primeiro elemento da lista?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Faça um [mcve], se tirou partes e não funciona podemos achar que o problema é por causa disto.

Comment: A parte que eu tirei apenas fazia a leitura do arquivo, não envolvia o problema em questão.

Comment: Faltam outros pedaços, e exatamente por faltar e você dizendo que não, não temos como saber se tem tudo o que precisa e aí fica difícil ajudar adequadamente.

Comment: Acredito que o problema está no uso dos ponteiros, lendo novamente eu percebi que estou mudando o parâmetro da primeira função (GetUsers) e (acredito que) isso não é possível. Mas eu não sei como fazer isso corretamente.

Comment: A linha em que eu faço "parametro = &struct" não surte o efeito esperado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há alguns problemas com o seu código. Em especial o que está impedindo que um nó seja atribuído a sua lista é a maneira como ponteiros de ponteiros (e valores em geral) são passados como parâmetros em C.

C adota a convenção de "passar por  valor".  A regra simplificada é: toda função enxerga uma cópia local dos argumentos que foram passados na chamada.

Quando você passa um ponteiro na chamada a função enxerga uma cópia do ponteiro, não o ponteiro original.

```
errorType GetUsers(userDataType **list)
{
    userDataType *first = // algo
    list = &first;
    return ok;
}
```

A instrução `list = &first;` pode ser lida como  "pegue o endereço" de `first` (que por sua vez é um ponteiro para uma `struct`) e atribua esse valor a `list`, que é uma cópia local de um ponteiro que aponta para outro ponteiro nulo. A cópia local é completamente independente do ponteiro de ponteiro original e é descartada quando a função sai de escopo.

O que você realmente quer fazer dentro do corpo da função é:

```
*list = first;
```

A diferença é sútil. Essa instrução pode ser lida como:

1. Pegue o valor para o qual minha cópia local de `list` aponta (i.e., um ponteiro que inicialmente aponta para `NULL`).
2. Pegue o valor de `first` (um endereço para um espaço de memória que você alocou).
3. Atribua 2 à 1.

O ponto aqui é que você está passando uma cópia de `list` como parâmetro. Nenhuma atribuição direta à uma cópia local sobrevive fora do escopo da função. Você não pode mudar diretamente o ponteiro de ponteiro original. Você pode porém mudar o valor para o qual a sua cópia aponta, o que por sua vez modifica o ponteiro original.

Ainda nessa frente, sabendo que seu argumento é somente uma cópia do endereço, eu não acho que faça sentido declarar um ponteiro de ponteiro no método `main`. Você pode declarar um ponteiro convencional e passar o endereço dele como argumento para a função, e.g.:

```
userDataType *usersList = NULL;
GetUsers(&usersList);
userDataType  *currentUser = usersList;.
```

Essa versão evita a declaração explícita de um ponteiro de ponteiro e deixa mais clara a intenção da chamada a `GetUsers`.

Enquanto essas mudanças devem resolver seu  problema original, há outras questões com o código... Fora de exercícios eu definitivamente repensaria a API, essa estratégia com uso de parâmetro de saída + retorno de *flag* me lembra padrões de codificaçâo dos anos 90. Chamar sua variável de `new` também não me parece ser a melhor das idéias (programadores C++ puxam o cabelo ao ler esse código).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Eu imaginei que estivesse mesmo alterando a cópia do ponteiro. Quanto a API, é para um trabalho de faculdade e, infelizmente, o professor manda fazer assim.